# ORA-39002 occurs during a Data Pump Import (IMPDP)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I exported a schema on 19c, with the parameter VERSION=18. When trying to import this schema onto a 18c environment, I am getting an error - "ORA-39002: invalid operation".

Oracle say online "Adding the sqlfile parameter allows the import to run with no errors to make a file of the DDL". This works but the SQLFILE that gets exported doesn't include my table data, etc.

Is there any workaround here, or what are my options to allow a successful import?

Comment: SQLFILE creates the SQL file of only DDLs

Comment: Yes, I saw that after seeing it's contents (never had to use it before). I just tried it as Oracle suggested it. Unfortunately I don't see a solution or workaround on the Oracle website where I can perform a successful import.

Comment: do a export of data only without version parameter and then import that data